# Routes and the dreaded 405

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've got a simple web API that registers on one route. At the moment I've got two because only one of them does what I need.

My application only has one controller and one Post method in that Controller. I've registered a single Route which always returns a `405 (method not allowed)`

The two routes are configured in the RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "app-events",
    routeTemplate: "events",
    defaults: new { controller = "Events" },
    handler: new GZipToJsonHandler(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration),
    constraints: null
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The Controller method is essentially this...

```
public class EventsController : ApiController
{
    public EventsController()
    {
        _sender = new EventHubSender();
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
    {
        // doing fun stuff here…

       return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

If I only configure the first route and post a request to *`http://devbox/events`* I will get a 405. However, if I add the second, default, route, and post to *`http://devbox/api/events`* I get back my expected `201`.

With both routes configured at the same time, the same pattern, the route explicitly bound to the Controller receives a post request and fails with a 405, but the other URL will work.

I've spent a long time looking around before conceding to ask the question. Most things I read have a lot to do with Webdav and I think I've followed every one of them to fix the issue. I am not very experienced with this stack, so nothing is very obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `RouteConfig` File. This is used for configuring the MVC routes not Web API routes.

So it would appear you are configuring the wrong file which would explain why the `api/...` path works as it is probably mapping to the default configuration in `WebApiConfig.Register`, which would look like

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

You would need to update that file with the other desired route

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "app-events",
            routeTemplate: "events",
            defaults: new { controller = "Events" },
            handler: new GZipToJsonHandler(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration),
            constraints: null
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Web API routes are usually registered before MVC routes which explains why it was not working with your original configuration.

You should also adorn the action with the respective `Http{Verb}` attribute.

In this case `HttpPost` so that the route table knows how to handle POST requests that match the route template.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post() {
    var requestMessage = this.Request;

    // async doing fun stuff here….

   return OK();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately that did not do the trick.  Ideally, I would like there to only be the single post method available for this service, but  if I isolate it to a single post route, I get the 405.  It's a common suggestion that works in some cases, but not for mine.

Comment: @bravelad figured it out. You were setting up the wrong route collection.